# Calling testimonial module in magento using code

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to show Testimonial on home page using PHP code in Magento

I already tried code below with getCollection or without getCollection function

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('turnkeye/testimonial');
```

May i calling correct Model ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module init code should be `turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial` instead of `turnkeye/testimonial`
if you want field by individual item then you can do this by `primary key of testimonial` table
.

```
$collection $model = Mage::getModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')>load(id);
```

if you want to fetch multiple items then you need Resource Collection

```
Mage::getResourceModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')->addFieldToSelect('*');
```

or

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')->getCollection();
```

for 
Random Collection

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')->getCollection();
 $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
```

Some reference

http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: I tried all if i tried Mage::getModel('turnkeye/testimonial') it's shows nothing but if i use ->load, addfieldtoselect or getCollection it's terminate the page (means error)

Comment: first of all .. what you want collection ya individual item

Comment: i want collection of testimonials

Comment: how can i get testimonial randomly

Comment: Amit have a look on this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139494/total-model-should-be-extended-from-mage-sales-model-order-total-abstract